# Create custom server CA for GCP databases

Tags: google-cloud-sql

For GCP managed SQL databases: we want to enable SSL/TLS using a common client cert across all our GCP databases. From reviewing the official google docs (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance), it seems the server certificate is **not** customizable and we require a different client certificate for each database instance.

Is there any solution where we can use a common client cert for multiple database instances?

Comment: 1) Google creates the client certificate. You cannot specify one. 2) Workarounds: a) use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy which manages connection security. b) implement a proxy that manages which certificate to use for each host. 3) My recommendation is to store certificates in Google Cloud Secret Manager and get the correct certificate set based upon the Cloud SQL instance name inside your application startup code/logic. This makes rotating certificates easy.